# Bash Script to Print to CSV File for specified number of lines

Tags: bash, csv, scripting

I want to be able to print a number of variables to a csv file. The variable differ depending on the file type. And it should also be possible to specific certain variables as options. For example i envisage it running like following:

```
./pickafile.sh format1 date time(optional) duration(optional)
```

example given:

```
./pickafile.sh watchtv 21112014 150000 10
```

This would do following

```
#!/bin/sh

var1=date (format DDMMYYYY)
time=time (format HHMMSS)
var2=duration (in seconds)
var3='Watchtv'
cheese='Cheddar'
num=20 #number times to print

case $file_type in
    watch_tv)
        cheese='stilton'
for i in 1..$num
do

## print to a csv file each row adding the 
echo $var1,$time+$var2,$var2,$var3,$cheese > $watch_tv.csv
done
        ;;
    watch_ppl)
        echo 'watch ppl??'
        ;;
    watch_animals)
        echo $'wahtc animals?'
        exit 1
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Unknown file- sure it isn't toxic?"
esac

done
exit
```

so the output of file would look add 60 seconds to each time period for 20 times

```
21112014,150000,10,Watchtv,stilton
21112014,150010,10,Watchtv,stilton
21112014,150020,10,Watchtv,stilton
21112014,150030,10,Watchtv,stilton
21112014,150040,10,Watchtv,stilton
21112014,150050,10,Watchtv,stilton
21112014,150100,10,Watchtv,stilton
etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I transformed your pseudo code into real code, corrected a few paste errrors. I am sure you are able to do the rest of the work.

```
#!/bin/sh

# $ date; date --date='now +10 Seconds'
# Fri Nov 21 17:28:33 CET 2014
# Fri Nov 21 17:28:43 CET 2014

var1=$(date '+%d%m%Y') # date (format DDMMYYYY)
time=$(date '+%H%M%S') # time (format HHMMSS)
var2=$4 # duration (in seconds)
if [ "" = "$var" ]; then
    var2=10 # default value
fi
# var3='Watchtv'
cheese='Cheddar' # default cheese
num=20 #number times to print

case $file_type in
    watch_tv)
        cheese='stilton'
        ;;
    watch_ppl)
        echo 'watch ppl??'
        ;;
    watch_animals)
        echo $'wahtc animals?'
        exit 1
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Unknown file- sure it isn't toxic?";;
esac

for (( i=1; i<=$num; i++)); do
    offset=$((var2*i)) # calculate the offset
    ## print to a csv file each row adding the
    #echo $var1,$time+$var2,$var2,$var3,$cheese > $watch_tv.csv
    echo "$(date '+%d%m%Y' --date="now +$offset Seconds"),$(date '+%H%M%S' --date="now +$offset Seconds"),$var2,$var3,$cheese"
done
```

output:

$ bash script.bash watchtv 21112014 150000 10

```
Unknown file- sure it isn't toxic?
21112014,174412,10,,Cheddar
21112014,174422,10,,Cheddar
21112014,174432,10,,Cheddar
21112014,174442,10,,Cheddar
21112014,174452,10,,Cheddar
21112014,174502,10,,Cheddar
21112014,174512,10,,Cheddar
21112014,174522,10,,Cheddar
21112014,174532,10,,Cheddar
21112014,174542,10,,Cheddar
21112014,174552,10,,Cheddar
21112014,174602,10,,Cheddar
21112014,174612,10,,Cheddar
21112014,174622,10,,Cheddar
21112014,174633,10,,Cheddar
21112014,174643,10,,Cheddar
21112014,174653,10,,Cheddar
21112014,174703,10,,Cheddar
21112014,174713,10,,Cheddar
21112014,174723,10,,Cheddar
```